# Firebase auth ошибка входа в систему Apple

Tags: swift, firebase, apple

Пытаюсь реализовать вход через Apple для android устройств, но столкнулся с проблемой приведенной в цитате и недопониманием, что мне нужно указать в "Domains and Subdomains" и "Return URLs".

> The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired. [ Error
> getting access token from https://appleid.apple.com/, OAuth2 redirect
> uri is: https://YOUR_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID/__/auth/handler,
> response: OAuth2TokenResponse{params: error=invalid_client,
> httpMetadata: HttpMetadata{status=400, cachePolicy=NO_CACHE,
> cacheDurationJava=null, cacheImmutable=false,
> staleWhileRevalidate=null, filename=null, lastModified=null,
> retryAfter=null, crossOriginEmbedderPolicy=null,
> crossOriginOpenerPolicy=null, crossOriginResourcePolicy=null,
> headers=HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Services id был создан по гайду apple и привязан к основному id.

Ключ был создан и задействован в firebase auth.

"OAuth code flow configuration (optional)" заполнен в соответствии с гайдом.

Единственное место, где может оказаться проблема это Web Authentication Configuration:

App id выбран верный.

Domains and Subdomains - указал адрес бэка в чем не уверен, что именно эту информацию нужно была там указать.

"Return URLs" указана одна ссылка, предоставленная firebase "https://project.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler"